# percent label position in pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, plot-annotations

Is there a way to change the default position of the percent label in a matplotlib pie chart?

Here is an example pie chart:

[image: My pie chart]

Which I have created using:

```
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors, explode=explode, autopct='%1.0f%%')
```

Now I don't like how some percent labels are intruding on other sections teritory (actually the only perpitrator in this example is the 9m section). Ideally I would like such labels to be outside the pie chart with an arrow of some sort pointing to the section, or alternativly just outside the section.

Comment: I've never used `plt.pie`, but you should be able to do what you want manually. the function returns `tuple (patches, texts, autotexts)`. `autotexts` is the sequence of `Text` containing the percentages. If you loop over them you should be able to find the `0.1%` (or whatever you want) and move the position of the text (to do this decently you might need to convert to/from circular coordinates).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can control the distance of the percents and labels from the center of the pie using `pctdistance=` and `labeldistance=`, try this on your code:

```
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.0f%%', pctdistance=1.1, labeldistance=1.2)
```

You can also set a radius of the pie using `radius=` (by default is 1)